# How to compile qtconnectivity (Bluetooth)?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu, bluetooth

I tried to do it by following commands:

```
./configure -developer-build -opensource -nomake examples -nomake tests
make module-qtconnectivity
```

But then I get the following when you start the program:

```
qt.bluetooth: Dummy backend running. Qt Bluetooth module is non-functional.
```

OS: Ubuntu 14.04

Here I was asked to set Bluez, but did not understand how to do it:
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-52692?focusedCommentId=319847&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-319847

Answer (score 1):

You compiled the module successfully. That message just states that you are using the Dummy backend hence you won't be able to connect to a device.

What OS are you developing on ?

Comment: And what do I do?
Ubuntu 14.04

Thank you in advance!

Comment: First thing, check that you have the bluez development packages installed.